# Batch file to rename files

Tags: batch-file

We have a couple of thousand files in a directory named like this:

```
EXP_10000021.XM_
```

And need to remove the leading 1 so the new file name is:

```
EXP_0000021.XM_
```

I'm no good with batch files - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Every file contains '1'?

Comment: do you specifically want a windows (DOS) batch file or unix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your filenames start all with `EXP_1` it's easy.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (EXP_1*.XM_) do (
  set "filename=%%A"
  set "newName=EXP_!filename:~5!"

  rem ** remove the ECHO when it seems to work
  ECHO ren !filename! !newName!
)
```

Comment: Copied your code into a test folder, then added a bunch of files named EXP_10000021.XM_ to EXP_10000028.XM_  Clicked the .bat file, and nothing happened.

Comment: Do you removed the `ECHO` in front of the `ren`?

Comment: No - told you I was no good at batch files!  Thanks a lot it works!  My manager wanted me to rename hundreds of files by hand - Awesome!!!!